# Como saber qual a variável maior de um vetor no R?

Tags: r, vector

Suponhamos que eu tenha as seguintes variáveis:

```
x = 2
y = 3
z = 5
```

E as transformo em um vetor:

```
vetor = c(x,y,z)
```

Pensei em usar a função `max`:

```
max(vetor)

[1] 5
```

Porém se eu usar a função `max` me retorna um número, sendo que na verdade eu gostaria de saber qual o nome da variável entre `x`, `y` e `z` é a maior, que nesse caso seria a variável `z`.

Como posso saber qual é a variável maior de um vetor no R?

Comment: Talvez `which.max`. Mas se quer o *nome*, então o vetor tem de ser um vetor com nomes, um *named vector*. Para criar o vetor será `setNames(vetor, c('x','y','z'))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O R não nomeia automaticamente os vetores, o ideal é você transformar em um data frame de uma linha.

```
vetor <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

Aí você pode fazer usar `which.max`, que te retorna a posição/variável com maior valor ou chamar essa posição pra ter a variável e o valor.

```
which.max(vetor)
vetor[which.max(vetor)]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela respostar vou testar.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro o vetor tem de ter nomes, só depois podem ser extraídos.
Pode fazer assim:

```
vetor = c(x, y, z)

vetor <- setNames(vetor, c('x', 'y', 'z'))

vetor
#x y z 
#2 3 5
```

Os nomes estão na linha de cima desta saída.
Outra maneira será:

```
names(vetor) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
```

E depois para obter o nome do elemento correspondente ao máximo, use `which.max`.

```
names(vetor)[which.max(vetor)]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver o problema com a função `sort`:

```
sort(colnames(vetor), decreasing = TRUE)[1]
[1] "z"
```

Lembrando que os valores devem estar nomeados.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você já tenha o vetor construído (como o `vetor`), e tenha apenas a necessidade de encontrar o escalar de maior valor, sugiro o uso do `for` com `ifelse` para poder transformar seu vetor numérico (`vetor`) em um vetor com nomes (`ww`) para posterior procedimento com `which.max`.

```
ww <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(vetor)) {
  w <- vetor[i]
  ww[i] <- ifelse(w == x, "x", 
              ifelse(w == y, "y",
                     ifelse(w == z, "z", "erro")))
  rm(w)  
}

c(ww)[which.max(vetor)]
```

```
> c(ww)[which.max(vetor)]
[1] "z"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou testar.